# Setting expanded output style in sass doesn´t work

Tags: sass

I want to change output style in my sass file to expanded but setting :

`sass --watch style.scss:style.css --style expanded`

doesn´t work for me. Instead it return me this

`Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: CP852 and UTF-8
  Use --trace for backtrace.`

Is there any possible to fix it? I´m not quite sure about it too because I´m new in Sass.But when I tried first  , things went well in my single line selector in compresed style .I did some changes in sass file, I have here now more selectors formated in expanded output style , but it seems that problem is that compiler still want to see my sass file in compresed output style because it gives me back this:

Compilation Error
Error: Invalid CSS after "body {": expected "}", was "{"
        on line 1 of sass/c:\Users\Doma\Desktop\Nové webovky\Javascript 
 & webovky\alfabeta\pionyr.sass

> > body { {

Can someone please help? Maybe is some basic thing but I really didn´t find solution to this and I searched in many sources

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

that happening because you use native language not english for your operation system to change that and make sure sass compiler working without errors write this in terminal/command line before you use sass compiling command `chcp 1252` after code activated use sass compile as expected `sass --watch style.scss:style.css --style expanded`

**update**
sometimes this error happening because silly mistake try this may help some causes this solution with helpfully change the path name from `c:\Users\Doma\Desktop\Nové webovky\Javascript & webovky\alfabeta\pionyr.sass` to `c:\Users\Doma\Desktop\Nov webovky\Javascript & webovky\alfabeta\pionyr.sass`
just take out `é` form the folder path and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your solution , I set chcp 1252 but and after typing

Comment: sass --watch style.scss:style.css --style expanded to my terminal it gives me back Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: Windows-1252 and UTF-8
  Use --trace for backtrace.

Comment: so shamely it still doesn´t work at all , I will try to fix it